# Domain model - Entity object between layers

Tags: domain-driven-design, entity

This might look like a beaten question, but could not find an answer at SO.

I am developing a simple Order Processing application. Quite bit a domain logic so i chose the domain model pattern. Every **Order** has a "**OrderType**" called "Ordinary" or "Express".

I have a Order entity and I exposed a int property called OrderTypeID as I thought I could store the OrderType's Id in that int field. Worked fine, but when I had to retrieve the order, I could populate back the integer "Order Type" Id, but I need to show the "OrderType - Express or Ordinary" in the screen. So Order entity when it goes down to persistence goes with Id but when it comes back it should become a text !!!!

How do I do this with respect to modelling the Order entity object, should I store the Ordertype as a whole entity (may be a OrderType class0, if yes, how will the repository for the "Order" class split the Ordertype so that i only persist the Id?

any points would be appreciated

Cheers
VJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few suggestions/observations.  `OrderType` sounds like a Value Type, not an Entity.  Perhaps you could implement as an enum?  Something like

```
public enum OrderType { ordinary, express };
```

Depending on your language you may be able to extend the enum to return a more friendly expression (e.g. by overriding `toString()` in java).  More details on java enums [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html).

Even if you can't/choose not to use an enum the principle is the same:  implement `toString()` to return a meaningful value.  In both cases it makes the human-readable value intrinsic to the OrderType class.  You should also make instances immutable (implicit with an enum).

Assuming `Order` is your aggregate root, you'd expose an interface that accepts/returns an instance of `OrderType` - not an integer.  For example:

```
class Order {
  //....

  public OrderType getOrderType() {...};
  public void setOrderType (OrderType orderType) {...}

  //...
}
```

hth.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not a beaten question and you might have to consider a lot of thinks in order to answer it properly. Those question are not only, unfortunatelly, related to DDD. You might have to consider the other criteria like the way you are going to persist this information on your database or if you have code which is dependent on the order type.

First question: What if you add an order type. Will you have to make change to the code in order for some operations to take those into consideration? if so you might define order type as an enum... i said you might... :) The order type could be that important that you could define specific class for each order depending on their order type and have a common base abstract class and use inheritance.

Second question: Do you really need to know the ID on your model? does order type 1, order type 2... mean anything on the model... I don't think so.Most probably than in all you bussness logic you will prefer to handle it has OrderType.OrderType1 or OrderType.OrderType2. Enum are easier to handle in this case.

Third question:You could ask yourself the same question on your database (if this is what you use as persistence). Do you need a fK relation to an order type Table? this has a performance cost. And you would probably use an ID for this... Could you not live with a DB Data type with predifined values. This is another topic but it challenges the idea that order type could be an entity...

And I could consider other things... There is a lot of thing to consider :)

The most common solution would be: to use an enum for the order type and to deal with the conversion on the repository if no order's operation logic is specific to the order type. If not consider inheritance and object orientation. Value type could be an option but will you have a lot of attributes for the order type? If not then no value type. :)

Hope this help.